# Specialize Many Templates for a Set of Types

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How to specialize many template for all kinds of scalar values? (such as `int`, `float`, `size_t`, `uint32_t`, and types defined in the `stdint` header)?

Can I avoid specializing each template for each of the types?
I don't want to use boost or other non-standard libraries if possible.

There are some solutions at [template specialization for a set of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349014/template-specialization-for-a-set-of-types):

1. Replace each template with multiple functions. One function for each scalar type. (But there are many templates. That would mean writing many functions.)
2. Fail if the template takes a non-scalar type. (But I also want to write template for array types. This would mean I need to change the names of the functions. One set of function names for scalar-scalar calculation. Another set for scalar-matrix calculation. Yet another set for matrix-matrix calculation. If I am trying to overload operators, i guess this won't work.)
3. Metaprogramming solution by Nawaz. Same problem as in solution 2 for this case.
4. Specialize a generic template for each scalar type. For example, write `inline long getRatio<long>`, `inline long getRatio<float>`, etc. Can work, but need to do that for the many templates.

Thanks again.

Example
(this uses Andrew's solution. adapted for an old std library. still need c++11. compiled with intel icc -std=c++11):

```
#define STD_POORMAN stdpoor
namespace stdpoor{
    template<bool B, class T = void>
    struct enable_if_t {}; 
    template<class T>
    struct enable_if_t<true, T> { typedef T type; };

    template<class T, T v>
    struct integral_constant {
        static constexpr T value = v;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef integral_constant type;
        constexpr operator value_type() const {
            noexcept return value;
        }
        constexpr value_type operator()() const {
            noexcept return value;
        }
    };

    typedef integral_constant<bool,true> true_type;
    typedef integral_constant<bool,false> false_type;
}
template <typename T>
class SimpleArray;

template <typename T>
struct is_ndscalar : STD_POORMAN::false_type {};
// Specialisations for supported scalar types:
template <> struct is_ndscalar<int> : STD_POORMAN::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ndscalar<float> : STD_POORMAN::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ndscalar<double> : STD_POORMAN::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ndscalar<long> : STD_POORMAN::true_type {};
template <> struct is_ndscalar<long long> : STD_POORMAN::true_type {};



template <typename T>
class SimpleArray{
    public:
        T* ar_data; //pointer to data
        int size; //#elements in the array
        SimpleArray(T* in_ar_data, int in_size){
            ar_data = in_ar_data;
            size = in_size;
        };

        template <typename T>
        void operator+=(const SimpleArray<T>& B){
            //array-array +=
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
                ar_data[i] += B.ar_data[i];
            }
        }

        template <typename T>
        STD_POORMAN::enable_if_t<is_ndscalar<T>::value, void>
        operator+=(const T b){
            //array-scalar +=
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
                ar_data[i] += b;
            }
        }
};

int main(void){
    int base_array[10];
    SimpleArray<int> A(base_array, 10);
    A += A;
    A += 3; 
}
```

Comment: What's your specific problem you're trying to solve? This is enormously broad.

Comment: I second Barry's request for a narrower problem statement. It's not clear whether you want to simply permit a number of templates to be used for anything you determine to be a "scalar type", for which SFINAE and an appropriate trait suffices, or whether you need those specialisations to contain different code for `int` compared to `float` (for example). A concrete example would likely result in more targeted advice.

Comment: writing a small library for array operation, similar to the numpy library of python. At this moment, I want to specialize each template for a calculation (such as operators *=, += etc) for scalar type, and also able to specialize the templates for all matrix types (matrix of int, matrix of float etc).

Comment: I see. let me add an example then.

Comment: Do you mean "specialise", or "enable"? Specialising means that you expect a different implementation for `float` compared to `int`, for e.g. `operator+=`. Enabling simply means you allow `float` or `int` (or any other identified "scalar type") instantiations, but not `Matrix` or `std::string` (or anything not identified as a "scalar type") instantiations. It's sounding like this is what you want, but hopefully the example will add further clarity.

Comment: i want specialize, not enable. The code for scalar-array calculation is not the same as the code for array-array calculation.

Comment: @rxu Indeed it is not. But you don't want to write a specialisation for `int`, another specialisation for `float`, and yet another specialisation for `double` - all of which are scalar-matrix calculations. You similarly don't want to write a specialisation for `Matrix<int>`, another for `Matrix<double>`, etc. What you want is to select a specialisation based on a *trait*, such as `is_scalar<T>` or `is_matrix<T>`. Your specialisations are then only for "matrix-scalar" ops and "matrix-matrix" ops.

Comment: @Andrew, you are right. That is what I want. I have also made an example as quickly as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condensing this down to a smaller example, based on the discussion in the comments on the question, you have a type `Matrix<T>` and you wish to implement, say, `operator+=`. The behaviour of this operator differs depending on whether the operand is a scalar or another matrix.

You therefore want to provide *two* specialisations; one for matrix-scalar operations, and one for matrix-matrix operations. Within those, you want to accept any valid scalar type, or any valid matrix type.

This is a classic use case for [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) and [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Define a trait `is_scalar`:

```
// Base template:
template <typename T>
struct is_scalar : std::false_type {};

// Specialisations for supported scalar types:
template <> struct is_scalar<int> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_scalar<float> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_scalar<double> : std::true_type {};
// etc.
```

And a trait `is_matrix`:

```
// Base template:
template <typename T>
struct is_matrix : std::false_type {};

// Specialisations:
template<typename T>
struct is_matrix<Matrix<T>> : std::true_type {};
// and possibly others...
```

Your operators will then be (member) function templates of the form:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_scalar<T>::value, Matrix&> operator+=(const T& rhs) {
  // Implementation for addition of scalar to matrix
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_matrix<T>::value, Matrix&> operator+=(const T& rhs) {
  // Implementation for addition of matrix to matrix
}
```

Note that [`is_scalar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scalar) is already provided for you by the standard library! All this leaves is for you to define `is_matrix` specialisations for any matrix types you support.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement this template only for certain types you can declare them in a .cpp file, similar to this: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

If you want to allow anything to be in this template, but explicitly declare certain types, this link might be helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization