# Specialize function template for set of types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Is it possible to create function template with different behaviour for different **sets** of types?

Suppose a function with template argument, that should accept **ANY** type, without compile fail

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T arg){
    std::cout << arg;
}
```

Surely, this won't compile for types having no `operator<<`. I want to write in `std::cout` only naive types (i.e. numerical, `std:string`, `const char *`), for other types there is meant nothing to print out.
So, I tried this (for simplification, i omitted checks for `std:string`, `const char *` )

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
void foo(T arg){
    std::cout << arg;
}

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
void foo(T arg){

}
```

That is, there must be generated overloaded functions with no potential ambiguity. Of course, the code does not compile, since parameters of template are not part of template signature (and thus there are two templates with same signature). So is there any way to play around?

I see the solution in making latter function as main template, and for stated types to create template specializations, but I don't want to bloat my code with identical definitions (and possibly there could be even more types for printing). Is there any way to specialize function template using `std::enable_if` or smth?

P.S. Boost is unrelevant
P.P.S. I've seen this answer [Specialize Many Templates for a Set of Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415312/specialize-many-templates-for-a-set-of-types), but i don't get how to adopt it, that is all types possible could be passed to function, not only few predefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried SFINAE using `std::enable_if` with return type ?

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type foo(T arg)
 { std::cout << arg; }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type foo(T arg)
 { }
```

Or tag dispatching ?

```
template <typename T>
void foo_helper (T arg, std::true_type const &)
 { std::cout << arg; }

template <typename T>
void foo_helper (T arg, std::false_type const &)
 { }

template <typename T>
void foo (T arg)
 { foo_helper(arg, std::is_arithmetic<T>{}); }
```

(caution: code not tested)

Comment: 1st one compiled well, but needed to "return arg;"

Comment: @AlexLarionov - sorry: what do you mean with "needed to 'return arg;'"? Do you need a function that return a value (`arg`?), not a `void` function? Anyway: 2nd one modified (forgotten `{}` at the end of `std::is_arithmetic`; sorry)

Comment: I mean, that 1st listing defines function template that returns value of type `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type`, and compiler claims them to be returned in both functions. If its possible to turn function into void-returning, I'd appeciate it

Comment: @AlexLarionov - `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type` is `void` (the default type for `std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>`) when `std::is_arithmetic<T>::value` is `true`; nothing (so substitution failure) otherwise. If you want a different type (example: `int`) you have to explicit as second parameter: `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int>::type`

Comment: ty, didn't notice the missing second parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can use the required expression `std::cout << arg` for SFINAE directly. Example:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo_imp(T&& arg, int) -> decltype(std::cout << std::forward<T>(arg), throw) /* -> is void */ {
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(arg);
}

template<typename T>
void foo_imp(T&&, long) {
    // Do nothing.
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& arg)  {
    foo_imp(std::forward<T>(arg), 0); // int is the best match for 0.
}

struct X {};

int main() {
    foo(1);   // calls foo_imp(int&&, int)
    foo(X{}); // calls foo_imp(X&&, long)
}
```

In the above `std::forward` is used to pedantically preserve the value category of `arg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(T arg){
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(T arg){
    std::cout << "not an arithmetic type\n";
}

int main() {
    foo(4.6);
    foo("bla");
}
```

This requires C++14 (use `std::enable_if` for C++11), and outputs:

```
4.6
not an arithmetic type
```

What is the difference?

Here we're creating an `int` with default value of 0 as second template argument, if the condition is met.